# How can I simulate a d3.forceManyBody() that operates on only a subset of nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

d3.forceManyBody() says it only operates on every node.  I'd like to be able to operate on a subset of nodes.  Specifically, I'd like two possibilities:

- apply the standard many-body force (attraction or repulsion) equally to all nodes in this subset of nodes
- given two subsets of nodes, A and B, all nodes in A are (attracted to/repulsed by) every node in B, with no impact to any other node

How can I pull this off?

One option that comes to mind is to figure out how to use d3.forceLink() to simulate the calculations of d3.forceManyBody(), and then create links between every node and every other node that is meant to have either an attraction or repulsion force applied.  If the two can be made to work, from a mathematical perspective, it might work, except for the performance issues.

Another option that comes to mind is to clone d3.forceManyBody() into something like d3.forceSelectiveManyBody() and tweak it to call the force.strength() accessor function once for every pair of nodes as part of its calculations.

Is there another, simpler, performant option that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Have a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39597440/4235784) to [*"Partial forces on nodes in D3.js"*](/q/39575319).

Comment: That'll work perfectly for the first scenario, where I want to apply a standard d3.forceManyBody() to only a subset of nodes.

Comment: What about the second scenario, where it is only to apply to a subset of node pairs?  I'm probably looking at making my own force function, aren't I?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing any more details, but it's probably somewhere down that road.

Comment: @JohnArrowwood, were you able to solve this? Am looking for something similar?

Comment: Yes.  See comment by altocumulus on Nov 15th regarding creating a many-body force that only affects a subset of nodes.  For the other, the solution was to generate lots of links between each node in A and each node in B.